# clocktable report - not display file without clocked time

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, org-clock-table

is-it possible thath clocktable report not display file without clocked time ?

For example I have :

```
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2020-06-10 mer. 10:53], for mercredi, juin 10, 2020.
| File                                        | Headline              | Time   |
|---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------|
|                                             | ALL *Total time*      | *4:03* |
|---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------|
| 20.04-forecast.org                          | *File time*           | *0:00* |
|---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------|
| 2006-systeme.org                            | *File time*           | *0:00* |
|---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------|
| 2020-05-12.org                              | *File time*           | *0:00* |
|---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------|

And i don't want to display line with 0.00 that don't have value for today.

Thanks for your feedback.

Best regards.
```

Answer (score 1):

That work with `:fileskip0 t`

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda :fileskip0 t :maxlevel 1 :block today 
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2020-06-10 mer. 11:15], for mercredi, juin 10, 2020.
| File         | Headline              | Time   |
|--------------+-----------------------+--------|
|              | ALL *Total time*      | *4:03* |
|--------------+-----------------------+--------|
| test1.org    | *File time*           | *0:01* |
|              | Analyse               | 0:01   |
|--------------+-----------------------+--------|
| test2.org    | *File time*           | *4:02* |
|              | Tache en cours [6/16] | 4:02   |
```